# does CVE-2014-0160 affects Sybase OCS-15_0?

Tags: security, sybase, sap-ase, heartbleed-bug

I believe Sybase OCS-15.0 has some utilities like certreq, certauth, which uses OpenSSL.
 does CVE-2014-0160 affects these components?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for SAP Technical Support.